# pygame font Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type

Tags: python, fonts, pygame, python-packaging

I started python programming a while ago and i really
like programing things with pygame.

So now i wanted to convert my perfectly fine working .py program to an executable using auto-py-to-exe.

So i started my program and everything seemed to work fine,
but as soon as the program gets to the point where it executes my
"screen_text_center" function the program crashes and i get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Arduino\LED_Mixer.py", line 109, in <module>
File "Arduino\LED_Mixer.py", line 10, in screen_text_center
File "venv\lib\site-packages\pygame\pkgdata.py", line 50, in getResource
File "venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1134, in resource_exists
File "venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1404, in has_resource
File "venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1456, in _has
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type
[12176] Failed to execute script LED_Mixer
```

This is the function that causes the error:

```
def screen_text_center(surf, text, pos, size, color):
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', size)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()

    text_rect[0] = pos[0] - text_rect[2] // 2
    text_rect[1] = pos[1]

    surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
```

I spent about two hours serching for an answer but i could not find what i was locking for

Edit: I replaced the Picture with the full error message
(it has a different name this time since i'm still working on it, but it's the same program)

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text, not image. And show FULL error - it seems you cut some lines at the end.

Comment: I don't use Windows so I don't have to create .exe but your error shows something about resources - maybe use full path to font file. BTW: it seems [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) is only GUI for [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) so maybe use directly `PyInstaller` which create special file with configuration and you can add information about some resources which you want to add to project.

Comment: `PyInstaller` has also documentation and page with most common problems - [When Things Go Wrong](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html). There should be also page for new problem - [How to Report Bugs](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/How-to-Report-Bugs). See more pages in [Documentation](http://www.pyinstaller.org/documentation.html)

Answer (score 0):

It happens because, PyInstaller does not support pkg_resources, which contains the 'freesansbold.ttf' font.

Here is the fix for it:
Add the following lines before the pygame font creation line in your py file:

```
import sys

if getattr(sys, "frozen"): # FROZEN executable
     font_family = "./freesansbold.ttf" # Hard-code a local path
else:
     font_family = pygame.font.match_font(font_family)
self.font_object = pygame.font.Font(font_family, font_size)
```

Now download the 'freesanabolt.tff' file from the internet and place it in the root folder of the python/executable file.

Reference link: http://pyinstaller.47505.x6.nabble.com/Pygame-and-PyInstaller-td2424.html